Grouping multi-line exceptions from kubernetes_logs using Vector
I would like to ask if anyone has used Vector to group multi-line exceptions from kubernetes_logs? If so, could you point me to a right direction?
The issue I'm facing is that the lines in the same exception are split into multiple entries, each with its own timestamp. Grouping by timestamp sometimes causes the logs to get shuffled, so the exception logs are no longer in the correct order. I need to collect the exception logs in the exact order they were printed by the application.
Afaik, kubernetes_logs does not support multiline 1, and they recommended to use the reduce transform [2]. However, the reduce transform documentation [2] is quite vague, and I’m a bit lost after reading through it. Has anyone successfully grouped multi-line exception logs before? I would appreciate any guidance.
1 https://github.com/vectordotdev/vector/issues/4211
[2] https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/transforms/reduce/

